# UITableView grouped: How do I change offset between two sections? 

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an UITableView grouped. I inserted UISegmentedButton in first section and second section. How do I change offset between two sections? I could set custom height of section.But I am looking for more elegant solution.

[image]

Comment: Try `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` or `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`?

Comment: Define elegant...custom heights are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using something this in FontType:

```
#define kHeaderHeight 40.0f

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, kHeaderHeight);
return [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you inserted the segmented buttons but the only way I know of to create more separation is by using the height for footer delegate method

Comment: you can customise the cell to insert anything in them and that's exactly what he has done.

Comment: Yea I know that, but he didn't specify the way in which he inserted them. He could have inserted them with custom header views too